# What is the difference between C* Cassandra Cluster and normal Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I have read about C* replication,
Is setting the partitioner in Cassandra setup to Murmur Partitioner makes the cluster C* cluster?

Comment: C* is an abbreviation for Cassandra. Nothing else (that I am aware of). What would be a _normal_ and what an _abnormal_ cluster to you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"C*" is an abbreviation for "Cassandra".  They are the same thing.

Comment: Any backstories to why C* is an abbreviation for cassandra?